# Running Gitlab and Openproject on one server

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I am running Gitlab and OpenProject on my apache2 server both run well on their own but once I start Gitlab OpenProject will respond with an error that the dir wasn't found. I think this might have to do with my Rewrite Rules in the Vhost file of gitlab here are both conf files

Gitlab.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName euve252630.serverprofi24.de
  ServerSignature Off

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all

    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
    ProxyPassReverse http://euve252630.serverprofi24.de/
  </Location>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

  # needed for downloading attachments
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

</VirtualHost>
```

openproject.conf

```
Include /etc/openproject/addons/apache2/includes/server/*.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName euve252630.serverprofi24.de
  DocumentRoot /opt/openproject/public

  ProxyRequests off

  # Can't use Location block since it would overshadow all the other proxypass directives on CentOS
  ProxyPass /openproject/ http://127.0.0.1:6000/openproject/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse /openproject/ http://127.0.0.1:6000/openproject/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: For starters both of your virtual hosts have the same ServerName.

Comment: I know, I need to run them on myhost.com/gitlab and myhost.com/openproject

Comment: Then they wouldn't be separate virtualhosts.  It's the same virtualhost with different configuration for those locations.

Comment: How exactly would I need to configure that? Sorry am quite new to vhosts and apache server stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup gitlab to listen on port 81.
Now you can visit the sites at

yoursite.com:81/gitlab

yoursite.com/openproject